# Is it not possible to play an MP4 video in a Javascript lightbox designed for images?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am using Firefox on Ubuntu Linux for testing. If I put the following link to an MP4 file in a page, the MP4 file plays in the browser window without any need for additional scripts or players:

```
<a href="/video/test.mp4" title="Test"><img src="/video/thumbnails/test.png" alt="" /></a>
```

However, I want to be able to stay on the same page, and play the video in a popup window, with the rest of the screen darkened. I believe this effect is called a "lightbox".

Thinking I could just use any lightbox and leave it to the browser to play the video file, I found an open source Javscript library for doing the lightbox effect, called [Lightbox2](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/). It's light and simple.

Following the instructions, I loaded the Javascript in the `<head>` of my web page, and then I added `data-lightbox="image-1"` to the link:

```
<a href="/video/test.mp4" data-lightbox="image-1" title="Test"><img src="/video/thumbnails/test.png" alt="" /></a>
```

When I click on the thumbnail image, the lightbox effect works, but the video does not display or play. The lightbox darkens the screen and displays a white square in the middle with no video file or player controls.

I know there are Javascript lightbox effects designed for playing videos, but, since the browser can play videos anyway, what differentiates those Javascript libraries from the one I'm using?

Why can't I play a video in this simple lightbox effect?

Can it be modified to play video, or do I need to scrap it and find a different library? Recommendations for similar video capable libraries are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I'm really sorry for getting back on this so late.

Okay so just an approach I had in mind at that time. It's left to you if you wanna try this out. But, if you want to avoid using third party scripts that you might have trouble tweaking here's simple approach. preferably, I'm going to use jquery code here just to make it look nice.

so lets say you want to have the video appear to pop up when the link is clicked. Why not just have our own div that contains a video element and then keep it hidden till we need it.

```
.
.
.
<body>
<div id="vid-container" style="display:hidden;position:fixed; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 padding:40px; text-align:center;">
<video id="vid"/>
 </div>
</body>
.
.
.
```

So, basically what I'm intending to do is that when a person click's on a video link, we'll use some jquery to toggle the popup div. As you can see that in the video tag I've only specified the id. This is only because I'm intending to set the video src and the codec after a particular link is clicked via javascript ( and a little bit of  jquery).

So suppose we have a link like so:

```
<a href="Link_URL" class="vid-link" ><image src="img_URL" class="vid-img"/></a>
```

And a person clicks on it, this is how I though you could handle it through the following script.

```
<script>
$(window).load(function(){ 
// first of all I'm manually setting the pop's width and height to fit the entire screen
$("#vid-container").css("width",window.innerWidth+"px");
$("#vid-container").css("height",window.innerHeight+"px");
$(".vid-link").bind("click", function(){

// first get the video url from the link href

var vid_url= $(this).attr("href");

// now grab hold of the video and set it up by plugging in the video url

var video= document.getElementById("vid");
video.type="video/.mp4";
video.src="+vid_url+";
video.controls=true;
video.autoplay=false;

// now toggle the popup visible

$("vid-container").fadeToggle("slow");

});// end of click handler

});// end of window.load event
</script>
```

We'll I think that should solve the bare necessities of your requirement. You could do alot more with it.

Hope this helps :)

Viva la HTML5!

Comment: Thank you for responding, but it is 100% necessary that the videos pop-up in a light box frame, which is why I'm trying to do that. Also, jwplayer is crazy expensive for commercial use, which is ultimately what I'm using this for. I'm not saying I wouldn't pay something for a decent Javascript library, but jwplayer is out of control on the pricing for what it's offering.

Comment: hmmm I see. Well I can see two ways of solving this problem:

firstly, I can see that you're not actually using a video tag at all, so may be that's why your video never shows up in the light box. 

Give me a couple of hours and I'll post back a really easy simple solution to this. ( sorry m traveling at the moment hehe )